How does the ETOTS system work on the A380, and what does it limit?
To my knowledge, all A380s with Trent 900s have thrust limited to 78% N1 until 35 knots speed (not sure if ground or airspeed). Would appreciate any expert knowledge on anything else that is limited and information about the system itself.
